Generalized Eigenvector Problem and Jordan normal form, kernal dimension etc...
Given a Matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and define $F_\lambda=\lambda I -A$. If $\lambda$ is such that $\det(F_\lambda)=0$, then there is at least one eigenvector $v_\lambda$ for which $F_\lambda(v_\lambda)=0$. However, if the multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $q$, then $q\geq $ the geometric multiplicity.
Now let's consider the map $F:V=\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and the sequence under $F$
$$V \mapsto F(V) \mapsto F(F(V)) \mapsto \dots \mapsto F^m(V) \, .$$
In the first step $V$ maps to $F(V)={\rm im}(F)$. However, $F(V)$ may still contain some part of the kernel $\ker(F)$, so essentially the only part of the image that maps to parts of the image again in the second step is ${\rm im}(F) \setminus \ker(F)$ and so you get that as long as $F^{m-1}(V)$ still contains some part of the kernel, the dimension of $F^m(V)$ reduces by at least one. Obviously this process can not go on forever in the finite dimensional case and there will be some integer $M$ such that $\forall m,m'\geq M$ the remaining subspace is invariant under the application of $F$ i.e. $F^m(V) = F^{m'}(V)$.
Not sure if this is trivial, but how do you show that $\dim(\ker(F^M))=q$, so the geometric multiplicity of $F^M$ is equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $\det(F)=0$? I mean surely if $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of multiplicity $q$, then the Matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{q\times q}$, so surely there are no more linear independent gen. eigenvectors than $q$, but what if there are multiple distinct eigenvalues e.g. $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ with multiplicites $q_1,q_2$? Couldn't the space of gen. eigenvectors be $q_1+1$ for $\lambda_1$ and $q_2-1$ for $\lambda_2$?
Thanks for help.

this quite literally the proof of Cayley Hamilton theorem
